# How to find Gate Delay

Tags: digital-logic, delay

I need to find the delay of a full adder. I searched for it but I couldnt find absolute information.

Sample delays : XOR - 8ns / AND - 2ns / OR - 2ns
[image]

What is the delay of this circuit?

**My Solution**

I think the delay is the maximum time.
For Full Adder : XOR + XOR = 16ns (max) Is it correct?
Another question is how can I find the delay of 4-bit adder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A full adder has three inputs and two outputs. To fully understand the timing, you need to consider each of the six input-output pairs separately. (In particular, note the delay from Cin to Cout!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single-bit adder, the worst-case propagation delay is the longest time it will take to get a stable output, which for this case is 16ns.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fESoEJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, for an N-bit adder, you should consider the path from the input's least significant bit (LSB) to a stable output's most significant bit (MSB)-- $$A_0 \rightarrow C_{out,0} \rightarrow C_{out,1} \rightarrow C_{out,2} \rightarrow S_3 (1)$$ (C<sub>in, i</sub> is implied, but not shown).

In the case of your circuit, we're given the following paths
$$A_i \rightarrow S_i = 16ns (2)$$
$$A_i \rightarrow C_{out,i} = 12ns (3)$$
$$C_{in,i} \rightarrow S_i = 8ns (4)$$
$$C_{in,i} \rightarrow C_{out,i} = 4ns (5)$$

From this, we calculate the longest path previously shown in (1). This calculates to be $$12ns + 8ns + 8ns + 8ns = 36ns$$

For more information, please refer to [this lecture on adder circuits](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/ee2_digital/Lecture%2014%20-%20Adder%20circuits.pdf)

Comment: I'm still a bit new to LaTex. Wasn't sure how to move the equation numbers to a right margin. Would appreciate some help in the edit.

Comment: I couldnt understand your explanation. Can you add a picture to show? And, What do LSB and MSB mean?

Comment: @g3d Schematic was added as well as LSB and MSB definitions up top.

Comment: I wrote an extended comment as a [separate answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/426148/11683). Please reply if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum delay is determined by the longest path from input to output. You are correct, 16ns is the maximum delay for this full adder. Inputs A or B to S is longer than any path to C<sub>out</sub> and is longer than input C<sub>in</sub> to either output.

The simplest way to find the maximum delay for a 4-bit adder is to first draw out the full schematic. For each stage (column of gates) starting left to right, find the maximum delay. I recommend you write the delay below the gate. To make sure you got the correct number, repeat the process this time going right to left and write this delay above the gate. If you got the same number there is a good change you did not make a mistake, otherwise try again.

With practice you'll start noticing patterns to speed up the process. 
<sub>*Hint:* max delay for each output of a full adder</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to add a comment here hence going for an answer. Referring to @Shabab's answer, shouldn't the total delay be 28ns instead of 36? Here is my understanding.

At 12 ns the Cin1(Cout0) is available, subsequently Cin2(Cout1) is available at 12+2+2=16 ns. At the same time the Sum S0 will be ready.

By (12 + 8) = 20 ns sum S1 will be available.

Going further, Cin3(Cout2) will be ready at 16+2+2 = 20 ns, and Sum S2 at 16+8 = 24ns.

Finally Cin4(cout3) will be ready by 20+2+2 = 24 ns and Sum S3 by 20+8 = 28 ns. Hence the total time elapsed to receive the complete output would be 28ns only.

S0 → 16ns

Cin1(Cout0) → 12 ns.

S1 → 12 + 8 = 20 ns

Cin2(Cout1) → previous carry + AND + OR i.e. 12+2+2 = 16ns (As first XOR would have been already completed by 8th second)

S2 → First XOR is already complete, so previous carry + XOR ie. 16+8 = 24 ns.

Cin3(Cout2) → previous carry + AND + OR i.e. 16+2+2 = 20 ns.

S3 → similarly 20+8 = 28 ns

Cin4(cout3) → similarly 20+2+2 = 24 ns

Am I missing something? Please help me understand.